# Deleted Calendar Still Shows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I deleted a calendar that a colleague created wrong. But it is still showing up in the LISTS. If you click on it you get an error "`Page not found`". But I can't get it to go away.

Comment: Did you see it in the recycbin? try to delete it from their. and also try from different browser / clear the browser cache and try again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talikng about the Lists in the Left Nav, then it was probably added manually in which it would not get cleaned up when the list was deleted. Go to Site Settings and click on either the Navigation or the Quick Launch link, depending on what features you have active in your site. Find the link to the calendar and delete it.